# How to take audio channels from a file and create an audio file with the channels as tracks?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have an audio file with multiple channels. How can I create a new file which has multiple audio tracks instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

`ffmpeg -i in.wav -filter_complex '[a:0]channelsplit=channel_layout=5c[out0][out1][out2][out3][out4]' -ac 1 -map '[out0]' -map '[out1]' -map '[out2]' -map '[out3]' -map '[out4]' out.webm`

Reference: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-21

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit imprecise but I assume you mean, break out the channels into separate and distinct audio files that are then combined, end to end in a new file.

For example:

Take a 6 channel file and isolate Front Left, Centre and Front Right using `map_channel`.

```
ffmpeg -i 6_Channel_ID.wav -map_channel 0.0.0 F_left.wav
ffmpeg -i 6_Channel_ID.wav -map_channel 0.0.1 F_right.wav
ffmpeg -i 6_Channel_ID.wav -map_channel 0.0.2 Center.wav
```

Combine them using `concat`

```
ffmpeg -y -i F_left.wav -i Center.wav -i F_right.wav -filter_complex "[0][1][2]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1" LCR.wav
```

I'm sure there must be a way to roll this into a single `filter_complex` command, using something like the `channelsplit` command.

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful. Ideally it would be a single FFmpeg command but I'll try that out.